# command.resolveMiddleware is not a function for AWS SDK when creating AMI from EC2 instanceID, wondering why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ami

I was working on an AWS SDK version 3 and was trying to create an AMI from an EC2 instance programmatically. The following is the script I use:

```
// Imports
// TODO: Import the ec2 client

const {
  EC2Client,
  CreateImageCommand
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-ec2')

function sendCommand (command) {
  const client = new EC2Client({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION })
  return client.send(command)
}

createImage('i-0672b492fb7f92bfd', 'hamsterImage')
  .then(() => console.log('Complete'))

async function createImage (seedInstanceId, imageName) {
  // TODO: Implement AMI creation
  const params = {
    InstanceId: seedInstanceId,
    Name: imageName
  };
  const command = new CreateImageCommand(params);
  return sendCommand(params);
}
```

The Instance ID was captured from the following JSON object for listing all the running instance on my code

```
[
  {
    AmiLaunchIndex: 0,
    ImageId: 'ami-0b5eea76982371e91',    
    InstanceId: 'i-0672b492fb7f92bfd',   
    InstanceType: 't2.micro',
    KernelId: undefined,
    KeyName: 'hamster_key',
    LaunchTime: 2022-12-27T03:10:12.000Z,
    Monitoring: { State: 'disabled' },   
    Placement: {
      AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1c',    
      Affinity: undefined,
      GroupName: '',
      PartitionNumber: undefined,        
      HostId: undefined,
      Tenancy: 'default',
      SpreadDomain: undefined,
      HostResourceGroupArn: undefined
    },
    Platform: undefined,
    PrivateDnsName: 'ip-172-31-80-74.ec2.internal',
    PrivateIpAddress: '172.31.80.74',
    ProductCodes: [],
    PublicDnsName: 'ec2-54-162-64-244.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    PublicIpAddress: '54.162.64.244',
    RamdiskId: undefined,
    State: { Code: 16, Name: 'running' },
    StateTransitionReason: '',
    SubnetId: 'subnet-09fbb143b92cb9d1b',
    VpcId: 'vpc-0ba9dffc72ac05ef6',
    Architecture: 'x86_64',
    BlockDeviceMappings: [ [Object] ],
    ClientToken: 'bd84c832-4429-482d-bdf9-323ddbb8cad4',
    EbsOptimized: false,
    EnaSupport: true,
    Hypervisor: 'xen',
    IamInstanceProfile: undefined,
    InstanceLifecycle: undefined,
    ElasticGpuAssociations: undefined,
    ElasticInferenceAcceleratorAssociations: undefined,
    NetworkInterfaces: [ [Object] ],
    OutpostArn: undefined,
    RootDeviceName: '/dev/xvda',
    RootDeviceType: 'ebs',
    SecurityGroups: [ [Object] ],
    SourceDestCheck: true,
    SpotInstanceRequestId: undefined,
    SriovNetSupport: undefined,
    StateReason: undefined,
    Tags: undefined,
    VirtualizationType: 'hvm',
    CpuOptions: { CoreCount: 1, ThreadsPerCore: 1 },
    CapacityReservationId: undefined,
    CapacityReservationSpecification: {
      CapacityReservationPreference: 'open',
      CapacityReservationTarget: undefined
    },
    HibernationOptions: { Configured: false },
    Licenses: undefined,
    MetadataOptions: {
      State: 'applied',
      HttpTokens: 'optional',
      HttpPutResponseHopLimit: 1,
      HttpEndpoint: 'enabled',
      HttpProtocolIpv6: 'disabled'
    },
    EnclaveOptions: { Enabled: false },
    BootMode: undefined
  }
]
```

The error I got was

```
C:\Users\jiali\OneDrive\Desktop\aws-developer-designing-developing\03\demos\before\node_modules\@aws-sdk\smithy-client\dist\cjs\client.js:13
        const handler = command.resolveMiddleware(this.middlewareStack, this.config, options);                                ^

TypeError: command.resolveMiddleware is not a function
    at EC2Client.send (C:\Users\jiali\OneDrive\Desktop\aws-developer-designing-developing\03\demos\before\node_modules\@aws-sdk\smithy-client\dist\cjs\client.js:13:33)
    at sendCommand (C:\Users\jiali\OneDrive\Desktop\aws-developer-designing-developing\03\demos\before\scripts\03\create-ami.js:11:17)
    at createImage (C:\Users\jiali\OneDrive\Desktop\aws-developer-designing-developing\03\demo
PS C:\Users\jiali\OneDrive\Desktop\aws-developer-designing-developing\03\demos\before\scripts\03> node .\manage-ec2-instance.js
```

I was confused as to why, is there any error on my code?

Comment: I also have this on the RDSClient

`TypeError: command.resolveMiddleware is not a function
    at RDSClient.send (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/smithy-client/dist-cjs/client.js:13:33)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you had the same issue I did which was accidentally forgetting to pass in the actual command object.

You use the `params` to build the command object but execute `sendCommand` with `params` instead of `command` as the parameter.

You should be executing `sendCommand(command);` and not `sendCommand(params);`